# Razor how to pass object from model source to target model after submit form

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I have following field, that display Name of Account.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.transaction.TargetAccount.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.transaction.TargetAccount.AccountId), @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.transaction.TargetAccount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

This is read only field. I would like to no pass this object into target Model.  Unfortunately,  reference objects are not passed. Only String ones. So AccountId is null on validation

Comment: Can you share the action method code where you are posting the data? Why you have validationError if the field is read-only? There is no input field rendered for AccountId field in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just display the `TargetAccount.Name`, and have a hidden field for the AccountId:
`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.transaction.TargetAccount.Name);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.transaction.TargetAccount.AccountId);`

Comment: and How razor know how to populate target model ( that which will be converted on SUBMIT action).

Comment: If you want my help you probably should have accepted my answer instead of the one from @JayChuah who just copied what I put.

Comment: ah sorry, His answer has been appear first on list

Comment: The standard way of implementing model binding in Razor pages is to have a public property on the PageModel and marking this property with the `[BindProperty]` attribute. Have a look at the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#targets

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden field in the Razor page.

So that when you submit the form, the model will pass on the hidden value like what Dave mentioned.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.transaction.TargetAccount.AccountId)
```